# What's the meaning of "Uzzi" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Fish Sauce, the amber-colored umami **Uzzi** of Southeast Asian cuisine. ([source](https://ourdailybrine.com/fish-sauce-taste-test/))

I assume it is a proper name. Google appears to suggest **Uzzi** is a biblical name, but nothing beyond it. What does it refer to here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simile, intended to be instantly comprehended, would, perhaps, have been more effective if the writer had spelled 'Uzi' correctly. It is the name of a small machine-gun developed in Israel. Notably powerful and capable of devastating results. It fires bullets so rapidly that a burst can cut a man in two. Strong, disruptive, effective, devastating if correctly handled, dangerous if not, etc. An Uzi is small but effective, and a small amount of SE Asian fish sauce can powerfully influence the flavour of a dish.